# How do I code an object moving/leaving from left to right side of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to code a train leaving the 'station' but I'm not sure where to start. My idea requires the train to appear from the left and disappear into the right side of the screen. I inserted an image of a sketch I did for this concept.

[image]

Comment: You can start from reading about HTML and CSS animations. Check this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out about CSS translate (a transform) at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate()

A useful feature of translate is that you can move an element by a % of its size.

So for your train you can start if off at translateX(-100%) which means it is just to the left of the viewport, out of site.

Then you want to move it to just off the right hand side of the viewport so you want to translate it 100vw;

Use a CSS animation to move it from left to right. This can be set up to run infinitely or just once or as many times as you want.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.train {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation-name: chug;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes chug {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(50vw);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(50vw);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="train"></div>
```

UPDATE: a pause has been put into the keyframes between 25% and 75% the train stays in the same place before moving off again.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot. I also have one more question if you could help me out, it would also be ideal if I could stop this 'train' in the middle. Do you have any suggestions on how to do that as well?

Comment: Do you mean for it to hang around in one place in the middle for a bit and then chug off again towards the right? You can do that in the keyframes. I'll do an edit.

Comment: Thanks again, it looks exactly what I had in mind. What was the reasoning for the percentages you added in keyframes? the 25% and 75%?

Comment: Only that that gets the train to stop for half the animation. You of course choose what you want, and you also need to look into the type of movement (ease, linear etc) to fit a train well.

Comment: Do you happen to also have an idea how I can make this train animation play during specific times of the day?

Comment: This requires Javascript checking the real time.

Comment: Oh, is there a way on html to allow it to auto play every few minutes without refreshing the page?

Comment: I suggest you learn about CSS animation. You can see how we paused the train by giving it a lot of the % - do the same for when the train is out of sight and make your duration several minutes long overall. Could you put any further queries into a new SO question please as these latter questions are not part of the original.

Comment: ok thank you, I really appreciated your help!